# Logo image doesn't load in IE but does in other browsers

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer

Just wondering what I did wrong? I've only just started making the site and have come across this problem, if someone could take a look at my code and tell me what I've done wrong that would be great.

The website is http://www.ratemc.com

Only the homepage is set up properly at this point, but the image should load in the banner at the top left (I haven't made a logo yet so it's just a random desktop screen I found).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if you see anything else wrong with my code then please mention it!

Thanks :)

Comment: i opened it in IE. I can see the logo image

Comment: what version of IE are you using? Are you sure compatibility mode is off?

Comment: try `background:url('../img/logo.png');` instead of `background-image`.. I think some of older version of browsers are not support `background-image`.. But I am not sure, you just try

Comment: What's `<!doctype php>` ???

Comment: As @Teemu hints at, your `<!DOCTYPE php>` is faulty. The doctype isn't decided by what file you're using (php,asp,aspx or whatever), but is something the browser uses to know what version of HTML that the page is written in. Change it to `<!DOCTYPE html>` to say that it's written in HTML5.